# Что за layout ? откуда он взялся?

Tags: java, android

Что за `layout`впервые сталкиваюсь.

`android:text='@{forecast.main.setTempFormatted(),default="3°"}'`

И что за метод подачи текста?
Это что-то новое для меня, в какую сторону капать?  подскажите ребят

```
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="xyz.justart.navimaptest11.MainActivity">
        <data>
            <variable
                name="forecast"
                type="xyz.justart.navimaptest11.api.TodayForecast"/>
        </data>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@{forecast.name,default=London}"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text='@{forecast.main.setTempFormatted(),default="3°"}'

            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="click (MainActivity)"
            android:elevation="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </layout>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#data_binding_layout_files

Comment: Спасибкииии))))